# How to sign Mac apps for distribution on Mac App Store

Tags: macos, store, sign

Greetings everyone.

I have this app I'd like to submit to the Mac App Store but I still don't get it about how to sign it before uploading it to the store.

So far I have downloaded these 3 certificates: a)AppleWWDRCA, b) MacAppIdentity and c)MacInstallerIdentity. But from there I got very confused about what to do next. I've read some articles but none is very clear to me. This is my very first App so this is kind of new to me.

So, do you know some good tutorials for signing apps for the Mac App Store?

Comment: Problem resolved. I just had the private keys missing from my certificates. Once I fixed that everything else went just fine.

Comment: Alex, any help on this? I'm doing the same and have no idea what to do w/ the certificates..

Comment: AlexLive, you should resolve this question if you found the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the [checklist (you need to log in)](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/checklist/)

Basically you'll need :

- A unique application id
- A distribution certificate
- A provisioning profile
- A icns file which will contain your app icon in all required sizes

Almost everything is done through iTunesConnect. You have to add your app, give the app ids, etc.

Let me know if you need more precise informations.

Comment: Looks like it has been removed. I will edit the post.